# Issue with higher order components: A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Why does the **higherOrderComponent1** function doesn't work and the **higherOrderComponent2** works as expected? According the documentation I don't seem to be doing something wrong, but as it is not working, I must be doing something wrong :-)

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html

You can find a sandbox version here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/MRwMnA2R

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

const higherOrderComponent1 = (name) => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      <div>{`Hi ${name}`}</div>
    }
  }
};

const higherOrderComponent2 = (name) => (
  <div>{`Hi ${name}`}</div>
);


const App = () => (
  higherOrderComponent1("Peter")
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: do `return <div>...` in `higherOrderComponent1`. The braces make a return statement necessary.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work unfortunately:

https://codesandbox.io/s/1wW9y6zjR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you're a little off on how to use a HOC. Here is a simplistic example that I will explain.

```
function giveColor( WrappedComponent, color ) {
    return class extends Component {    
        componentDidMount() {
            this.wrapperEl.children[ 0 ].style.color = color;
        }

        render() {
            console.log(this.props)
            return (
                <div ref={ ( el ) => this.wrapperEl = el }>
                    <WrappedComponent { ...this.props } />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

const PrintName = ({ name }) => (
    <div>{ name }</div>
);

const PrintRedName = giveColor( PrintName, "#ff0000" );
```

You would use PrintRedName as follows: `<PrintRedName name="Bubowski" />`

The `name` property you provide will get passed through to the wrapped component because of the `{ ...props }` on the `<WrappedComponent />` call in the render method of the returned class from the HOC.

The HOC is used as a function on another component as follows: `const PrintRedName = giveColor( PrintName, "#ff0000" );`

I'm calling the giveColor HOC with PrintName component as the first argument, and the color I want to set as the second.

In the HOC I wrap the WrappedComponent in a div that I give a `ref` that I use to change the style.color property of the first child of the `ref`.

This is a contrived example, but I hope it helps you understand :)

Some good examples of HOCs are `connect()` from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) and `withRouter()` from [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router)

EDIT: In response to your latest question:

I edited your linked to code to the following to make it work, please read the in code comments.

```
const wrapComponent = (WrappedComponent) =>
  class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          I wrapped:
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

const ComponentA = ({name}) => <div><b>{name}</b></div>;
const ComponentB = wrapComponent(ComponentA);

// You had...
/*

No need to wrap a component wrapping itself, but the problem here is,
You're nesting evalutions by doing { ...code } inside
() => ( single evaluation )

const App = () => (
  { wrapComponent(ComponentB) }
)
*/


const App = () => (
  <ComponentB name="My name" />
)

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Good catch, but that doesn't seem to work unfortunately:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1wW9y6zjR

Comment: I don't think something's wrong with the higher-order-component stuff, but more with the fact that I can't make the function return a correct react element.

This block renders just fine:
`const myFunction1 = () => {
  return <div>Hello</div>
};
`

But this doesn't:

`const myFunction2 = () => {
  return class extends Component {    
  }
};
`

If I add the render method, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. A few comments for possible other readers:

* Coming from a functional programming word, I had to get used to the fact that a function written `const doSomething = () => <return something />` works just as expected, but whenever you use `{ ... }` you need to use a return statement.
* Higher Order Functions are not to be used directly in code (e.g. in render methods `{ connect(..) }`). This still boggles me a bit.

Here's some working code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/G6N5mnr7L

Comment: Just a last question, maybe someone can clear something up, see this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/v2ppY6RVX

`const ComponentA = ({name}) => <div><b>{name}</b></div>;
const ComponentB = wrapComponent(ComponentA);

const App = () => (
  // <ComponentB name="Hello world!" />
  // wrapComponent(<ComponentA/>)
  // wrapComponent(ComponentA)
  // {wrapComponent(<ComponentA/>)}
  // {wrapComponent(ComponentA)}
)`

To me at least from the second line on, at least one should have worked as well. Is there some magic going in React that only the first line works?

Comment: So the HoC is really a function that takes a component and returns a new component that wraps the component provided to the HoC function, providing it additional functionality.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it would not need to matter in what kind of way you use this function. For some reason, I cannot use it directly in a render method, while I assume that this should be possible. Would it be possible to have a look at the code and see what I mean? https://codesandbox.io/s/v2ppY6RVX For some reason it doesn't allow me to show code nicely here in the comments.

Comment: I looked at it. When you invoke the `wrapComponent` function you are creating the HoC. So in your expression you made a HoC, but you never actually used it. You would need to do that outside of the render method, save it to something and then use it in the render.